# Wamp MySQL error started

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

My Wamp suddenly stopped working and is giving some MySQL error. The green tray  is showing, and my pages/sites on localhost not running.

Here is the first error:

[image: First error]

Here is the second error:

[image: 2nd error]

How can I resolve these errors without losing my MySQL db and all the websites that are running on localhost?

Comment: Sounds like something for the folks at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Stuff like this does not just happen by magic. You must have done something to cause it to happen, even if you dont realise what it was that you did.

Answer (score 1):

I have just copy php_mysql.dll file from old backup and its start working,

Thanks